# Sequelize raw query return empty array if query has WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

When the sql statement contains WHERE clause the result is coming as empty array.
My version are

```
"pg": "^7.8.0",
"pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
"sequelize": "^4.42.0",
"sequelize-cli": "^5.4.0"
```

code is

```
let $seq = models.sequelize,
    sql = `SELECT to_char(start_time::timestamp, 'MM-DD-YYYY') as dates FROM market_holidays WHERE start_time >= NOW()::date`;
const holidays = await $seq.query(sql, {
    type: models.Sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW
});
```